# Looping in a method that returns boolean

Tags: c, loops, boolean, cs50

So I have a method here that I'm writing in C. I just need to understand how this works.

```
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }
}
```

*Yes this is from CS50 but that's irrelevant.

So I have the method here and I am trying to return either true or false. If I put the true inside the loop, isn't it going to return true repeatedly until this loop finishes? How can I return true once?

Comment: Why do you have a `java` tag if you're writing in C?

Comment: @Moana Lisa Show how candidates is declared. Otherwise your question will be down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the function `return`s, the loop is "abandoned" and will not/can not continue.

This for loop will only execute i = 0, because it `return true` if `name` matches `candidate[i].name` and returns false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the `return` statement in a function, that function is done. Finished! It can only return *once*. In your code, the loop will *always* return during the first run of the `for` loop, because, even if the `if` test fails, the `return false` is **inside** that loop.

You need to put the `return false` *outside* (after) the loop:

```c
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true; // Match found ... job done, function is finished!
        }
    //      return false; // Here, we would return on first loop that didn't match
    }
    return false; // Here, we return false if the loop finished without finding a match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

strcmp is a function that compares two strings. If the two strings are the same then it returns zero. Looks like the container array is an array of objects.
So is any of the object has its property name same as the required name then you increment the vote count property of that object by 1 and then return true. Returning true indicates that yes there was a candidate with that name in the list. If there was no candidate with the required name in the list then the if block will not get executed and the control will come out of the loop and execute the return false statement which indicates there was no candidate by the required name.

```
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        //check if the name exists
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            //increment the vote of that candidate by 1.
            candidates[i].votes++;
            //return true stating there was a candidate in the list by that name.
            return true;
        }
    }
    //return false stating that there was no candidate by that name.
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this a C code then it is a bad function definition that relies on global variables such as `candidate_count` and `candidates`. You have to pass these variables through parameters to the function.

If to assume that candidates is an array with the element type something like `struct Candidate` then the function should be declared at least like

```
bool vote( const struct Candidate candidates[], size_t candidate_count, const char *name );
```

Also it is a bad idea to use the typedef name `string` for the type `char *` because using this typedef name you can not declare the type `const char *`.

The problem with your function definition is that the return statement

```
return false;
```

is placed inside the for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
{
    if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
    {
        candidates[i].votes++;
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}
```

while it shall be after the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
{
    if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
    {
        candidates[i].votes++;
        return true;
    }
} 

return false;
```

Also it is not a good programming style when such a simple function has several return statements.

Nevertheless using your function declaration its definition can look more clear and readable if to rewrite it the following way

```
bool vote( string name )
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < candidate_count && strcmp( candidates[i].name, name ) != 0 )
    {
        i++;
    }

    if ( i != candidate_count ) candidates[i].votes++;

    return i != candidate_count;
}
```